# Time limit exceeded online judge

Tags: java

This is the problem :

> Input
>   The first line of input will contain the number of test cases, T (1 ≤ T ≤ 50). Each of the following T
>   lines contains a positive integer N that is no more than 80 digits in length.
>   Output
>   The output of each test case will be a single line containing the smallest palindrome that is greater
>   than or equal to the input number.
>   Sample Input
>
> ```
> 2
> 42
> 321
> ```
>
> Sample Output
>
> ```
> 44
> 323
> ```

I keep having time limit exceeded when i submit to the code to online judge ( 3 seconds limit)

```
  class Main {

static String ReadLn (int maxLg) 
    {
        byte lin[] = new byte [maxLg];
        int lg = 0, car = -1;
        String line = "";

        try
        {
            while (lg < maxLg)
            {
                car = System.in.read();
                if ((car < 0) || (car == '\n')) break;
                lin [lg++] += car;
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            return (null);
        }

        if ((car < 0) && (lg == 0)) return (null);  // eof
        return (new String (lin, 0, lg));
    }


    static boolean isPalandriome(String s){
        String newString = "";
        for(int i =s.length()-1;i >= 0; i--){
            newString += s.charAt(i);
        }
        if(newString.equals(s))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            BigInteger entredNumber;
            String input;
            input = Main.ReadLn(10);
            int tests = Integer.parseInt(input);
            List<BigInteger> numbers = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
            for (int i =0;i<tests;i++)
        {
            input = Main.ReadLn(100);
            entredNumber = new BigInteger(input);
                numbers.add(entredNumber);

        }


            for(int i=0;i<tests;i++){
                BigInteger number = numbers.get(i);

                while(!isPalandriome(String.valueOf(number))){
                    number  = number.add(BigInteger.ONE);
                }
                System.out.println(number);

            }

    }
}
```

I can't find what takes too much time in my code.

Comment: Searching one by one takes too long time,or example, if the input is `10000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000`. You have to develop more effective algorithm.

Comment: Concatenating strings in a loop is inefficient. You can reverse a string much more efficiently (and correctly) using `StringBuilder.reverse()`.

Comment: Can you help me with the algorithm ? how should i proceed ?

Comment: @AndyTurner That would make the palindrome check more efficient, but I don't think that will solve the problem. The concept of looking at each number from the input to the result is broken. Assume ten checks per nanosecond. In three seconds the program could test at most 30 billion numbers, nowhere near enough given up to 80 digit input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last coded Hope you find this helpful took 0.10 seconds

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        CustomReader cr = new CustomReader(1000000);
        int T = cr.nextInt(), fIndex, bIndex, fStartIndex, bStartIndex;
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        byte[] input;
        boolean isAppend1 = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
            input = cr.nextInput();
            fStartIndex = bStartIndex = cr.getCurrInputLength() / 2;
            isAppend1 = false;
            if (cr.getCurrInputLength() % 2 == 0) {
                bStartIndex--;
            }
            fIndex = fStartIndex;
            bIndex = bStartIndex;
            while (input[bIndex] == input[fIndex]) {
                if (bIndex - 1 < 0) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    bIndex--;
                    fIndex++;
                }
            }
            if (input[bIndex] > input[fIndex]) {
                while (bIndex >= 0) {
                    input[fIndex++] = input[bIndex--];
                }
            } else {
                if (input[bStartIndex] < 57) {
                    input[bStartIndex] = (byte) (input[bStartIndex] + 1);
                } else {
                    bIndex = bStartIndex;
                    while (bIndex >= 0 && input[bIndex] == 57) {
                        input[bIndex] = 48;
                        bIndex--;
                    }
                    if (bIndex >= 0) {
                        input[bIndex] = (byte) (input[bIndex] + 1);
                    } else {
                        input[0] = 49;
                        if (fStartIndex != bStartIndex) {
                            input[fStartIndex] = 48;
                            bStartIndex = fStartIndex;
                        } else {
                            input[fStartIndex + 1] = 48;
                            bStartIndex = fStartIndex = fStartIndex + 1;
                        }
                        isAppend1 = true;
                    }
                }
                while (bStartIndex > -1) {
                    input[fStartIndex++] = input[bStartIndex--];
                }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < cr.getCurrInputLength(); j++) {
                output.append((char) input[j]);
            }
            if (isAppend1) {
                output.append("1");
            }
            output.append("\n");
        }
        System.out.print(output.toString());
        // genInput();
    }

    private static class CustomReader {
        private byte[] buffer;
        private byte[] currInput = new byte[1000000];
        private int currInputLength;
        private int currIndex;
        private int validBytesInBuffer;

        CustomReader(int buffSize) {
            buffer = new byte[buffSize];
        }

        public int nextInt() throws IOException {
            int value;
            byte b;
            while (true) {
                b = getNextByte();
                if (b > 47 && b < 58) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            value = b - 48;
            while (true) {
                b = getNextByte();
                if (b > 47 && b < 58) {
                    value = (value * 10) + (b - 48);
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return value;
        }

        public byte[] nextInput() throws IOException {
            byte b;
            this.currInputLength = 0;
            while (true) {
                b = getNextByte();
                if (b > 47 && b < 58) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            currInput[currInputLength++] = b;
            while (true) {
                b = getNextByte();
                if (b > 47 && b < 58) {
                    currInput[currInputLength++] = b;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return this.currInput;
        }

        public int getCurrInputLength() {
            return this.currInputLength;
        }

        private byte getNextByte() throws IOException {
            if (currIndex == buffer.length || currIndex == validBytesInBuffer) {
                validBytesInBuffer = System.in.read(buffer);
                currIndex = 0;
            }
            return buffer[currIndex++];
        }
    }

    public static void genInput() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.println((int) (Math.random() * 1000000000));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, there's a little problem you skipped the case where the first entred number is already palandriome.